# Clicking button within drop down from excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to click a drop down option from a HTML page with my VBA script, however I am struggling to work out how to do this.

Essentially my code opens the page, inputs some variables, then I want to select to export this as PDF from the list.

```
    Dim oIE As Object
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim XMLHTTP As Object
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Dim Disbuttons As Object
     
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

With appIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "WEBPAGE"
    
End With

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until appIE.readyState = 4
      
appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").Value = "03/10/2022"
appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl05_txtValue").Value = "04/10/2022"
appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00").Value = "21669"

appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl04_ctl00").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))


appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu").Click
  appIE.document.querySelector("[title='PDF']").Click
```

The part that isn't working is;

```
    appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu").Click
  appIE.document.querySelector("[title='PDF']").Click
```

The HTML for the drop down is:

```
<DIV id=ctl32_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu class=MenuBarBkGnd style="POSITION: absolute; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-TOP: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; Z-INDEX: 1; DISPLAY: none; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; VISIBILITY: hidden" _oldDisplayMode="block"><DIV class=DisabledButton><A onclick="$find('ctl32').exportReport('XML');" title="XML file with report data" class=ActiveLink style="TEXT-DECORATION: none; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="XML file with report data" _selected="false">XML file with report data</A> </DIV>
<DIV class=DisabledButton><A onclick="$find('ctl32').exportReport('CSV');" title="CSV (comma delimited)" class=ActiveLink style="TEXT-DECORATION: none; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="CSV (comma delimited)" _selected="false">CSV (comma delimited)</A> </DIV>
<DIV class=DisabledButton><A onclick="$find('ctl32').exportReport('PDF');" title=PDF class=ActiveLink style="TEXT-DECORATION: none; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="PDF" _selected="false">PDF</A> </DIV>
<DIV class=HoverButton><A onclick="$find('ctl32').exportReport('WORDOPENXML');" title=Word class=ActiveLink style="TEXT-DECORATION: none; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Word" _selected="true">Word</A> </DIV>
<DIV style="HEIGHT: 149px; WIDTH: 26px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; FILTER: alpha(opacity=5); Z-INDEX: -1; TOP: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: black; opacity: 0.05"></DIV></DIV>
```

With specifically the exportReport('PDF') being the one of interest.

Any advice on this and where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is probably not the best attribute to search for (in context of the whole document), its not guaranteed to be unique, or that the first instance is the element you are looking for.

```
Dim Menu As Object
Dim Item As Object
Set Menu = appIE.document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu")
If Not Menu Is Nothing Then
    Set Item = Menu.querySelector("div[title=PDF]")
    If Item Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "couldnt find item"
    Else
        Item.Click
    End If
Else
    Debug.Print "couldnt find menu"
End If
```

Looking at the HTML, you can probably skip all of that by directly calling the export function. (in theory the following should work)

```
appIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "$find('ctrl32').exportReport('PDF');"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Can confirm that both methods work perfectly. In the essence of simplicity I've gone with the execscript option!

I did think that there must be a way to just call the $find individually but wasn't sure how to go about it. Thanks again.